# How to detect app store review bots inside code

Tags: ios, app-store

Whenever I upload a new release, Apple's review bots for probably every screen size/device are opening my app and getting out for a moment.

The problem is this behaviour is messing up my analytics, so I wish to detect which user is a bot and which is a real user. How can I achieve this? Does these bots leave some kind of footprint or device ID?

Comment: Your best option is likely to take note of the release number, the upload date, and the release date for that build. Filter out analytics events before the release date.

Comment: I think its much easier to make an if case with, "ignore analytics 24 hours after upload"

Comment: I think you should keep a flag at the server when to 'enable' 'disable' the analytics and enable it after release